# Why Constructor is called before the copy-constructor is called?

Tags: c++, constructor

I am learning class constructor.

As you can see in this website : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_copy_constructor.htm

On the first example code in the site,

```
Normal constructor allocating ptr
Copy constructor allocating ptr.
Length of line : 10
Freeing memory!
Freeing memory!
```

I have difficulties in understanding why the copy constructor is called after the normal constructor.

I think there is no reason the copy constructor is called.
Are the following two code lines different?

```
Line line(10);  or
Line line = Line(10);
```

or the function 'display' calls copy constructor?

Comment: Please write your post so that people don't have to follow links to answer your question.

Comment: What @godel9 is saying is that in your post you should include the relevant code, the inputs, the expected outputs, the actual outputs, indicate where you have problem understanding the code, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy constructor is being called from

```
display(line);
```

Where display function is taking a copy of line object as it's parameter. If you change the display function's definition to

```
void display(Line& obj);
```

Copy constructor will be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

Yes those two lines are different.

`Line line(10);` creates `line` , passing `10` to the constructor.

`Line line = Line(10)` first does `Line(10)` which creates a temporary object by passing `10` to the constructor of the temporary object; and then it creates `line` by passing that temporary object to the copy-constructor. The temporary object is then destroyed.

The temporary object should be optimized away (this is called *copy elision*). Some compilers don't perform copy elision in Debug mode, or if you pass switches to disable copy elision.